# Can a cuda array simultaneously have a cudaArraySurfaceLoadStore and a cudaArrayLayered flag?

Tags: arrays, cuda, gpu

For devices of compute capability 2.0 and higher, a CUDA array, created with the cudaArraySurfaceLoadStore flag, can be read and written via a surface object or surface reference using the functions described in Surface Functions.

On the other hand, a CUDA array, allocated with the flag cudaArrayLayered can have a layered structure.

Is it also possible to have CUDA array with both flags, so that it can be written to in a specific kernel and accessed (layeredwise) in a second kernel?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  In all cases you would need to use the layered access functions, eg., you would need to use [`surf?Dlayeredwrite()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#surf1dlayeredwrite-object) to write to it, and similarly to read from it.

minimal example, 2D layered:

```
$ cat t2106.cu
#include <helper_cuda.h>
const int layers = 2;
const int xdim = 3;
const int ydim = 3;
__device__ float d_arr[xdim*ydim*layers] = {1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8};
__global__ void write_kernel(cudaSurfaceObject_t surf)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < layers; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < xdim; j++){
      for(int k = 0; k < ydim; k++){
        surf2DLayeredwrite<float>(d_arr[i*xdim*ydim+j*ydim+k], surf, j*sizeof(float), k, i);
      }
    }
  }
}

__global__ void read_kernel(cudaSurfaceObject_t surf)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < layers; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < xdim; j++){
      for(int k = 0; k < ydim; k++){
        printf(" layer:%d x:%d y:%d val: %f\n", i, j, k, surf2DLayeredread<float>(surf, j*sizeof(float), k, i));
      }
    }
  }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc =  cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
    cudaArray *dev_cu_array;
    cudaSurfaceObject_t surf;
    cudaResourceDesc res_desc;
    memset(&res_desc, 0, sizeof(res_desc));
    cudaExtent extent = make_cudaExtent(xdim, ydim, layers);
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc3DArray(&dev_cu_array,
                                    &channelDesc,
                                    extent,
                                    cudaArrayLayered|cudaArraySurfaceLoadStore));
    res_desc.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
    res_desc.res.array.array = dev_cu_array;

    checkCudaErrors(cudaCreateSurfaceObject(&surf, &res_desc));

    write_kernel<<<1,1>>>(surf);
    read_kernel<<<1,1>>>(surf);
    checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    checkCudaErrors(cudaDestroySurfaceObject(surf));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaFreeArray(dev_cu_array));
}
$ nvcc -o t2106 t2106.cu -I/usr/local/cuda/samples/common/inc
$ compute-sanitizer ./t2106
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
 layer:0 x:0 y:0 val: 1.000000
 layer:0 x:0 y:1 val: 1.100000
 layer:0 x:0 y:2 val: 1.200000
 layer:0 x:1 y:0 val: 1.300000
 layer:0 x:1 y:1 val: 1.400000
 layer:0 x:1 y:2 val: 1.500000
 layer:0 x:2 y:0 val: 1.600000
 layer:0 x:2 y:1 val: 1.700000
 layer:0 x:2 y:2 val: 1.800000
 layer:1 x:0 y:0 val: 2.000000
 layer:1 x:0 y:1 val: 2.100000
 layer:1 x:0 y:2 val: 2.200000
 layer:1 x:1 y:0 val: 2.300000
 layer:1 x:1 y:1 val: 2.400000
 layer:1 x:1 y:2 val: 2.500000
 layer:1 x:2 y:0 val: 2.600000
 layer:1 x:2 y:1 val: 2.700000
 layer:1 x:2 y:2 val: 2.800000
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```